# Implementing a WebView database quota delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

How do I implement this method (see below)? I'm new to Objective-C and I'm just not getting it right.

From: http://lists.apple.com/archives/Webkitsdk-dev/2008/Apr/msg00027.html

> By default databases have a quota of 0; this quota must be increased before any database will be stored on disk.
>
> **WebKit clients should implement the WebUIDelegate method `- webView:frame:exceededDatabaseQuotaForSecurityOrigin:database:` and increase the quota as desired when that method is called.** This method is defined in WebUIDelegatePrivate.h. It was added too late in the previous release cycle to make it into a non-private header. It would be worthwhile to file a bug about moving this call to WebUIDelegate.h so that it is part of the official API.

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In whatever class you've defined as the delegate for your WebView you need to implement that method, something like this:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender frame:(WebFrame *)frame exceededDatabaseQuotaForSecurityOrigin:(WebSecurityOrigin *)origin database:(NSString *)databaseIdentifier {
    unsigned long long newQuotaBytes = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    [origin setQuota:newQuotaBytes];

    // origin also responds to -usage method to return current size for all databases in this origin
}
```

Comment: Can confirm this solution worked great using a WebView with a UI delegate viewing http://html5demos.com/database

Answer (score 1):

Got some help from a discussion board:

There seems to be an implementation of this method included in WebKit's
WebKitTools in their public SVN. (The class is named UIDelegate).
http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebKitTools/DumpRenderTree/mac/U...

I'm assuming you've created a delegate for your WebKit view. In that
delegate class, create a method with the signature:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender frame:(WebFrame *)frame
exceededDatabaseQuotaForSecurityOrigin:(WebSecurityOrigin *)origin
database:(NSString *)databaseIdentifier;
```

You can probably use a modified version of UIDelegate's implementation:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender frame:(WebFrame *)frame
exceededDatabaseQuotaForSecurityOrigin:(WebSecurityOrigin *)origin
database:(NSString *)databaseIdentifier
{
    static const unsigned long long defaultQuota = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    [origin setQuota:defaultQuota];
}
```

I haven't tried this, so YMMV.

Jon

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final answer.

I was using the MiniBrowser sample app.

In MyDocument.m I added this function:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender frame:(WebFrame *)frame exceededDatabaseQuotaForSecurityOrigin:(id)origin database:(NSString *)databaseIdentifier
{
    static const unsigned long long defaultQuota = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    if ([origin respondsToSelector: @selector(setQuota:)]) {
        [origin setQuota: defaultQuota];
    } else { 
        NSLog(@"could not increase quota for %@", defaultQuota); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8975014/146099 - it's a slight variation on Jeff's Answer.