# localStorage and 'file:' protocol not persistent, SQLite gives SECURITY_ERR

Tags: javascript, sqlite, webkit, local, local-storage

## Introduction

I work with RapidWeaver — Mac OS X CMS application — and it uses no server environment. It has an editor and a preview mode. The preview mode is a Webkit based renderer, and I can use 'Inspect Element', like you normally could do in Safari.

I want to store some settings for a toolbar, either using **localStorage or SQLite**. I have read some information about indexedDB, though I have found no concrete implementations on how to use it.

### Problems with localStorage

localStorage works fine when I stay in the preview mode, when I switch between editor and preview mode the url — location.href — is slightly altered:

```
file:///private/var/folders/s7/x8y2s0sd27z6kdt2jjdw7c_c0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/RapidWeaver/98970/document-143873968-28/RWDocumentPagePreview/code/styled/index.html

file:///private/var/folders/s7/x8y2s0sd27z6kdt2jjdw7c_c0000gn/T/TemporaryItems/RapidWeaver/98970/document-143873968-29/RWDocumentPagePreview/code/styled/index.html
```

document-143873968-**28** *changes into* 
document-143873968-**29**

What I have read about localStorage, that it's basically globalStorage[location.hostname] for FireFox. As far as I know globalStorage is not supported in Safari, so I can't try that.

### Problems with SQLite

When I try to open a database:

```
var shortName = 'mydatabase';
var version = '1.0';
var displayName = 'My Important Database';
var maxSize = 65536; // in bytes
var db = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
```

I get this in my console:

```
SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.
```

That basically wraps up my question, I will appreciate any answers or comments sincerely.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following solution: [Implementing a WebView database quota delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353808/implementing-a-webview-database-quota-delegate) with a few modifications I was able to get it to work.

The following delegate method worked for me (place in your webViewDelegate):

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender frame:(WebFrame *)frame exceededDatabaseQuotaForSecurityOrigin:(id) origin database:(NSString *)databaseIdentifier
{
  static const unsigned long long defaultQuota = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
  if ([origin respondsToSelector: @selector(setQuota:)]) {
    [origin performSelector:@selector(setQuota:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithLongLong: defaultQuota]];
  } else { 
    NSLog(@"could not increase quota for %@", defaultQuota); 
  }
}
```

By default the database is given 0 bytes, which results in the vague error message you get above. The above method is called after an attempt is made to create a database when there is not enough space. Note that this method is defined in WebUIDelegatePrivate.h ( http://opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-7533.16/mac/WebView/WebUIDelegatePrivate.h ) and using may preclude you from submitting your app to the mac app store.

Answer (score 1):

localStorage is a html5 mechanism to give scripts a bit more space than cookies.  Safari supports it: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SafariJSDatabaseGuide/Name-ValueStorage/Name-ValueStorage.html

I don't know offhand what, if any, path restrictions it should have for file:/// based apps.

Edit: looking into the path restrictions further, I see that what you got should work with Safari, FF recently fixed a bug that would keep it from working there: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show%5Fbug.cgi?id=507361

Comment: It's not working for me, also I tested localStorage on localhost using MAMP with no luck.