# websql ios. An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent

Tags: javascript, ios, html, web-sql

I am using websql in an application that I'm building. It's working great until I access it on ios (iPad).

I get the following error and the application breaks:

**An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.**

I'm using the html5sql js lib and the error happens here:

**html5sql.database = openDatabase(name, "", displayname, size);**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540904/localstorage-and-file-protocol-not-persistent-sqlite-gives-security-err/8975014#8975014

Comment: OK I figured it out.
I was trying to create it at a large size so it was failing.  It will ask user to increase on its own if need be.